# Upper bound of the number of disconnected zeroes of multivariate polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Suppose polynomial $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ has degree $d$, can we bound the zeroes of $f$? If the zeroes are connected we consider it as one zero. For example, $f=xy-1$ has 2 zeroes. I guess the number is $nd$ ($n=1$ is trivial) but I haven't found literature about it.

Comment: Could you give some more examples? I take it the two zeros you're referring to in the example you gave are the two branches of the hyperbola $xy=1$, but if that's right I'm confused about your conjecture for, say, $x^3 y - 1=0$ (this has $n=2$, $d=4$ but also two zeros by your count, doesn't it?)

Comment: @ChrisLewis Right, 2 zeroes for your example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not bound by $nd$: consider, for example, $f = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i^2 - 1)^2$ - it has degree $4n$, but has $2^n$ zeroes $(\pm 1, \pm 1, \ldots, \pm 1)$.

This is not an easy question: there is a bound found by Milnor (theorem 5.1 [http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/tools1.pdf](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/tools1.pdf)) that number of connected components is at most $d \cdot (2d - 1)^{n - 1}$. There were some improvements on that, but I think the exact bound is still now known.